# Wordpress sync with phpbb

Tags: database, users, forum

How can i sync the wordpress database users with phpbb database users so i can log on each one with the same user at any time and if there`s no user created for the wordpress to log in with the phpbb one and vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this plugin for doing this:
[phpBB Bridge](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-phpbb-bridge/)
also you can find more useful description in this stackoverflow Question:
[How to integrate phpBB with Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122822/how-to-integrate-phpbb-with-wordpress)